# Applying function to entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do the following code, which works fine. It needs to be applied to every row of the DataFrame `df`. `class_dct` contains a different NLTK `NaiveBayes` classifier for each of 9 regions.

```
for region in regions:
    new_app=[]
    for title in df.booktitle:
        nlp_genre=class_dct['Classif_%s'% region].classify(features(title))
        new_app.append((title,region,nlp_genre))
```

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please provide some context for your question.  Tell us what this code does, and make that the title of the question. See [ask].

Comment: To gain performance and eliminate these bottlenecks, you could use the techniques/tools I mention at 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051553/performance-nested-loop-in-numba/41069372#41069372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the Python interpreter will optimise most or all of this on its own, but you could try a **list comprehension** and **removing an intermediate variable**:

```
new_app = [(title, region, class_dct['Classif_%s'% region].classify(features(title))) for title in df.booktitle]
```